# react-native xcode 9.2 ios simulator is very slow

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

today i had to update my xcode to 9.2, it come with simulator ios 11.3, so after update i run my reactnative project and there is something wrong with simulator drawing app.

now app stuck when rendering, and i have to toggle cmd-D to force simulator to draw.

sometimes it just render white background and few black lines, again after i press cmd-D to toggle menu, the app draw correct view.

i googled around and there are few bugs with ios 11.3 simulator, so i downloaded ios 10.0 from xcode >  preferences > components, yet problem is same.

any one facing same problem ? and how can we fix that ?

GIF bellow shows problem, when i navigate from green tab to blue tab, the view is frozen -as if app was stuck, but actually this is just graphic glitch-, after i press cmd-D it show correct render
[image: gif of error]

**Slow Animation is disabled in case u was wondering"**